How to add event to non-static panel?
First of all, I would like to point out that I am quite a beginner in C#.
My code is:
private static void addImageToPanel(imageData[] images, Panel panel)
{
Panel imagePanel;
PictureBox imageImage;
Label imageLabel;

Size imageSize = new()
{
    Width = 80,
    Height = 80,
};
Size imagePanelSize = new()
{
    Width = 100,
    Height = 100,
};
const int posX = 60;
const int posY = 140;

foreach (imageData image in images)
{
    if (!panel.Controls.ContainsKey(image.key))
    {
        imagePanel = new()
        {
            Name = image.key,
            Size = imagePanelSize,
            Left = posX * x + margin,
            Top = posY * y + margin,
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
        };
        //Error here VVV toolStripClick (CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'member')
        imagePanel.Click += new EventHandler(toolStripClick);
        imageLabel = new()
        {
            Name = image.key + "_text",
            Text = image.name,
            ForeColor = Color.White,
            Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8),
            Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        };
        imageImage = new()
        {
            Name = image.key + "_image",
            Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\..."),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            Size = fileSize,
            Dock = DockStyle.Top,
        };
        panel.Controls.Add(imagePanel);
        imagePanel.Controls.Add(imageLabel);
        imagePanel.Controls.Add(imageImage);
    }
}
}

where "toolStripClick" is:
private void toolStripClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
}

I can't understand why this doesn't work. Adding static to "toolStripClick" doesn't help.
Even tried to do a for loop after adding all the images, like this:
for (int i = 0; i < mainPanel.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    mainPanel.Controls[i].Click += new EventHandler(toolStripClick);
}

It doesn't display any errors other than a warning (CS8622: Nullability ref...), but it still doesn't work.
Edit:
Nevermind I just found that deleting static from "addImageToPanel" fix it, partially as it do not work on panel, but work on label...
Is there a way to make it work on panel? Or any workaround?
Edit2:
Replaced "focusPanel" to "imagePanel". (My mistake while copy pasting. It was and is imagePanel not focusPanel.)

If this is "winforms" you might want to add the respective tag. (Or the tag of whatever UI framework this refers to. It just looked like WinForms at first glance)

If you need instance member (i assume focusPanel is one) here why is addImageToPanel static? You can only use static stuff in a static member method.

Counterquestion if this would work and lets say you have that form ten times created and shown which focusPanel on the ten forms should be used in the static method? Remember static means its only once there and does not belong to a specific instance of the form. You would need to hand over the concrete current instance of the form you want to use. Without the static keyword that is implicit the method gets a reference to the current instance its defined for (you can then use this.focusPanel)

Changing
private static void addImageToPanel(imageData[] images, Panel panel)

to
private void addImageToPanel(imageData[] images, Panel panel)

and
imagePanel.Click += new EventHandler(toolStripClick);

to
imageImage.Click += new EventHandler(toolStripClick);
imageLabel.Click += new EventHandler(toolStripClick);

fix it partialy.
Probably I'm already going outside of this thread problem, but how I can get info which image I clicked to remove or edit it?

Yes that is a different question at the end.  Look at the sender property you get in the eventhandler.

But sender have only basic functions eg. ToString, GetType.

Because you could add the same Handler to totally different controls as you do here. So sender could be anything and therefore its just defined as object. Test the type of sender then cast it to that type needed (or check the type through debugging in its current state of your code, that's extremely advisable to do anyways because of its very instructiveness) or simply compare references if that's sufficient here like if (sender == imageImage).

I found that 'Control c = sender as Control;' works to get all informations. But there is warning about possible null, tho sender should never be null? From what I understand.

String emphasis on "should" but checking it does not hurt.
